# Boolean value in backing bean not updated with ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to set the value in the backing bean based on the checkbox selection. 
Here is the Checkbox:

```
...
<f:view>
<p:panel header="HEADER">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="TEST_CB" itemLabel="TEST CB"
                             value="#{myBB.test}">
        <p:ajax execute="@this" update="someComponent"/>
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
...
```

In the backing bean, I have a boolean property `test` with public getter and setter.

When I click on the checkbox, the setter in the backing bean is called(so far so good), but the value which is passed as a parameter is always false. 
I've been messing with it for two hours, trying different combinations of p:ajax parameters, immediate and partial on the p:selectBooleanCheckbox, I've also tried using h:selectBooleanCheckbox, but it is still false.

I use Apache MyFaced 2.1.10 and Primefaces 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button was not in the form.

After adding `<h:form>` tag, everything is ok.